# How can I use a method as a item in a dictionary? Python 2.x

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I want to use the method only if I get the item in the for.
But, When the cicle starts all methods are called. 
I've tried to use dict[key](fuction parameters) but I don't know the parameters
in the final part of the cicle for.

---

```
class Func():
    def LD(self,r,r2):
        self.reg[str(r)]=self.reg[str(r2)]    
        self.cic[0]=self.cic[0]+4
        self.cic[1]=self.cic[1]+1
        self.cic[2]=self.cic[2]+1
        print 'LD '+str(r)+','+str(r2)

class Data(Func):
    reg={'A':0,'B':0,'C':12,'D':0,'E':0,'H':0,'L':0,'F':0,'IX':0,'IY':0}
    cic=[0,0,0]

Dat=Data()


LI={'C':Dat.LD('A','B'),'D':Dat.LD('A','C')}
LD={'A':Dat.LD('D','E'),'B':Dat.LD('D','F')}
L={'1':LD,'2':LI}

Cod=['1A','2D']
cont=0
for temp in L:                                                           
    if Cod[0] in temp:                                                   
        if Cod[1] in temp[cod[0]]:                                    
            temp[cod[0]].get(cod[1])
```

---

Comment: What does this mean: "I don't know the parameters in the final part of the cicle for." ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not putting methods into the dictionary in the first place, you're *calling* methods, and putting the *results* in the dictionary. For example:

```
LI={'C':Dat.LD('A','B'),'D':Dat.LD('A','C')}
```

This calls `Dat.LD('A', 'B')` immediately, and makes it the value for the `'C'` key.

This is exactly what the [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function is for. As the docs say:

> The `partial()` is used for partial function application which “freezes” some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a new object with a simplified signature. For example, `partial()` can be used to create a callable that behaves like the `int()` function where the base argument defaults to two:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> basetwo = partial(int, base=2)
>>> basetwo.__doc__ = 'Convert base 2 string to an int.'
>>> basetwo('10010')
18
```

So, for your problem, you want a new object that behaves like the `Dat.LD` method, but where the arguments are already "frozen in" as `'A', 'B'`:

```
from functools import partial

LI={'C': partial(Dat.LD, 'A', 'B'),
    'D': partial(Dat.LD, 'A', 'C')}
```

Or you can just explicitly create a new function with `def` or `lambda` that wraps up the method call:

```
LI={'C': lambda: Dat.LD('A', 'B'),
    'D': lambda: Dat.LD('A', 'C')}
```